# Orchard body content when editing wont appear?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Not sure what information is going to be helpful here so ill just take you through it. I have just installed Orchard and pointed an IIS site at the install, everything is fine right up until I try and edit a page as this is all it shows:[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser's developer tool console?

Comment: No I dont but I can see the text in the source code and that it has some inline styling setting the body text visibility as hidden?! Why would it be doing this?

Comment: There should be a textarea, visible by default, and an editor, not visible at first, but brought by script, which is why there is almost certainly a script error causing this.

Comment: I will investigate thank you for responding